# REG_EPAREN in php

Tags: php, error-handling

Im using the `eregi()` function for matching the string but it is giving the following error:

> PHP Warning:  eregi() [function.eregi]: REG_EPAREN in /a/b/c/mysite/file.php on line 59, referer: xyz.com

I'm using this function here :

```
if(eregi($check,$in))
{
    $titles=ucfirst(substr($desc, 0, 38));
}
else
{
    $titles=$title." : ".$add_desc;
}
```

where `$check` and `$in` contain text type data which can be anything from alphanumeric  to special characters.

What could be the possible reason for this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you really mean to be doing a regular expression check?  If so, where are you getting `$check` from?  If it includes parentheses that you expect to match as literals, are you correctly escaping them?

Comment: @Reuben : yess i mean regular expression here.Iam getting parenthesis in $check and im escaping them too before doing this eregi thing but still this error comes.

Comment: I you are using regular expressions, and the error comes out from there, isn't the best to post here that regex?

Comment: stristr just did the thing for me.............Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [eregi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) does a 'case insensitive regular expression match' $check should contain a valid [regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), not just 'text type data'. You should probably use [stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `$check` contains characters that mess up the regular expression. If you can, cou should move to the `preg_*` regular expression functions and run `$check` through [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

```
if(preg_match(preg_quote($check), $in)) ...
```